# automatically download pdf from email link

Tags: windows, pdf, email, download-manager, email-client

I get some emails with a download link to a pdf file from a website.

When i get the email with the link i need to automatic download the file.

Is there some software for it?

It is a pop3 mail and use gmail as mail client. I have Windows 10.

All software i tried is only when the pdf is directly attached to the email. Like this: [attachment downloader](http://gearmage.com/maildownloader.html) But can not handle the link.

In the end i need to print the attachment but i got seperat software for that...

Comment: What mail client do you use ?

Comment: please add more details to your question, like the OS it should run on, etc...!